# Using the Draw Tool to Create a Grease Pencil Fill Will Result in One Adjoining Segment Which Cannot Be Subdivided

Tags: edges, grease-pencil, draw-mode

While in Draw Mode, using the Draw tool will allow you to use a lasso-like freehand action to create a grease pencil fill. Blender is set up to know that whenever you release the mouse during this draw operation, the fill should auto-close and auto-complete. Unfortunately, the adjoining segment that is produced as a result of releasing the mouse is not exactly like the other segments that make up the resulting fill, because, unlike those others, it cannot be subdivided. This issue doesn't arise if any tool other than Draw is used to create a fill (such as box or circle). Only the Draw tool has this issue. Is this a bug? If so, I imagine a workaround could be to never use the draw tool if I want my fill-based segments to have even subdivisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TheLabCat explained, the line between the Start and End point isn't a "real" edge. There is a few different ways to make it behave like a regular one, in Edit mode:

- **Close the stroke**: Select the stroke and press <kbd>F</kbd> to close it. This will automatically set the stroke to cyclic and add a whole bunch of new point in between the Start and the End.

If that's too many points for your taste, you can:

- **Set the stroke to cyclic**: Select the stroke then in the "Stroke" menu click on "Toggle Cyclic". This will create a new "real" edge that you can then subdivide by selecting both ends and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> (change the number of subdivisions in the pop-up menu).

If you don't want to set the line to cyclic for whatever reason, then:

- **Shrink the fake edge**: Select the End point then press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude it and position it as close as possible to the Start point. You can now subdivide that new line like in the previous example.

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, I believe I understand your meaning. However, I would assume you intend for the extruded vertex to be merged with the destination vertex. Otherwise, the "problem" segment has only been vastly shortened, but not eliminated. Well, I can't seem to get the extruded vertex and the destination vertex to merge. Moreover, I can't get them to vertex snap together either, as vertex snapping seems not to work with grease pencil objects. I used the 3D cursor to do it, and still can't merge the points. What was your thinking on how your first suggestion should be attempted?

Comment: Your second suggestion is much better, so thank you for it. It brings a less than satisfactory workflow, however, because after using the "Cyclic" option, the segment in question still must usually be subdivided to be of much use in any sculpting efforts that follow. But subdividing can't be done on individual segments, only on the stroke as a whole, meaning that a Simplify action must be performed after subdividing, which seems a rather tedious workaround. One wonders why segments cannot be targeted as if they were poly edges, which would likely be any user's standard assumption.

Comment: For my purposes, the extra points created in your third suggestion are ideal, and not at all excessive. At least so far as I can see. Thanks for providing three different options. It allowed me to find the one that worked best for me.

Comment: It turn out I was wrong about lone segments not being able to be subdivided. With a segment's end points selected, subdivide will be performed only on what's directly between those selected points.

Comment: @R-800 Probably would have been better if I'd listed the options in the opposite order... soz :)

Comment: @R-800 okay, I tried to make the answer clearer and changed the order to be more useful

Answer (score 1):

This is actually because that last segment is faked: it’s just a “return to base” instruction, as the stroke must have a start and end point. See this in action using a build modifier on a cyclic stroke.

I was frustrated too by this one, and I hope there is a workaround soon.